# How to create ruby uuid from bytes?

Tags: ruby, uuid

C# contains method to generate Guid from bytes:

```
byte[] bytes = {107, 97, 155, 242, 36, 52, 182, 87, 67, 223, 163, 166, 7, 175, 123, 223};
Guid guid = new Guid(bytes); // => {f29b616b-3424-57b6-43df-a3a607af7bdf}
```

How to write ruby code which will generate the same uuid as C#? The uuid defined in [Ruby:SecureRandom](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html) doesn't accept any parameters.

Comment: "Other systems, notably Microsoft's marshalling of UUIDs in their COM/OLE libraries, use a mixed-endian format, whereby the first three components of the UUID are little-endian, and [the last two are big-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Encoding)." Are you kidding me, Microsoft?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to skin a cat, simple and easy to understand:

```ruby
a = [107, 97, 155, 242, 36, 52, 182, 87, 67, 223, 163, 166, 7, 175, 123, 223]

def _guid(ints, reverse=false)
  hexes = ints.map { |b| b.to_s(16).rjust(2, '0') }
  return hexes.reverse.join if reverse
  hexes.join
end

def guid(ints)
  '%s-%s-%s-%s-%s' % [
    _guid(ints[0...4], true),
    _guid(ints[4...6], true),
    _guid(ints[6...8], true),
    _guid(ints[8...10]),
    _guid(ints[10..-1]),
  ]
end

puts guid a # => f29b616b-3424-57b6-43df-a3a607af7bdf
```

Comment: Defining a function within a function is not idiomatic Ruby. You might as well define `_guid` at the same level as `guid`, since it will be defined at that scope anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes development process involves writing code, not only calling existing libraries:

```
bytes.each_with_object([]) do |b, acc|
  acc << [] if acc.size == 0 ||
               acc.size == 1 && acc.last.size == 4 ||
               acc.size > 1 && acc.size < 5 && acc.last.size == 2
  acc.last << b.to_s(16).rjust(2, '0')
end.map.with_index do |e, idx|
  idx < 3 ? e.reverse : e
end.map(&:join).join('-')
#⇒ "f29b616b-3424-57b6-43df-a3a607af7bdf"
```

Comment: Looks like this stuff _should_ be in the library :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I disagree. Generating UUID based on given bytes ruins the whole idea of UUID. It’s like having `rand(bytes)` implemented like `bytes.pack('c*')`.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't ruin, not one bit. These are two equally valid use-cases: generation and deserialization. If ruby had a uuid/guid __type__ in the stdlib, you bet your back it'd contain this functionality. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way, using nothing but `sprintf`. I'm not sure if I love it or hate it.

```
arr = [107, 97, 155, 242, 36, 52, 182, 87, 67, 223, 163, 166, 7, 175, 123, 223]

fmt = "%4$02x%3$02x%2$02x%1$02x-" \
      "%6$02x%5$02x-%8$02x%7$02x-%9$02x%10$02x-" \
      "%11$02x%12$02x%13$02x%14$x%15$x%16$x"

str = sprintf(fmt, *arr)
# => "f29b616b-3424-57b6-43df-a3a607af7bdf"
```

This uses `sprintf`'s `$` flag to explicitly specify the order for the hex digits, e.g. `%4$02x` means "print the fourth octet in the arguments as two hex digits."

We could, of course, generate the format string:

```
positions = [[4, 3, 2, 1], [6, 5], [8, 7], [9, 10], 11..16]
fmt = positions.map {|a| a.map {|d| "%#{d}$02x" }.join }.join("-")
# => "%4$02x%3$02x%2$02x%1$02x-%6$02x%5$02x-%8$02x%7$02x-%9$02x%10$02x-%11$02x%12$02x%13$02x%14$02x%15$02x%16$02x"

str = sprintf(fmt, *arr)
# => "f29b616b-3424-57b6-43df-a3a607af7bdf"
```

...but at that point you might as well just do this:

```
positions = [ [ 3, 2, 1, 0 ], [ 5, 4 ], [ 7, 6 ], [ 8, 9 ], 10..15 ]
str = positions.map {|a| a.map {|n| "%02x" % arr[n] }.join }.join("-")
# => f29b616b-3424-57b6-43df-a3a607af7bdf
```

You can see all of these in action on repl.it: https://repl.it/@jrunning/FamousRewardingApplescript

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a really straightforward way by converting the bytes to an array of hex strings, inserting `-`'s in the right locations, and then joining the array.

```
def to_uuid(bytes)
  hex = bytes.map { |b| b.to_s(16).rjust(2, '0') }
  [4, 7, 10, 13].inject(hex) { |hex, n| hex.insert(n, '-') }.join
end

to_uuid([107, 97, 155, 242, 36, 52, 182, 87, 67, 223, 163, 166, 7, 175, 123, 223])
# => "6b619bf2-2434-b657-43df-a3a607af7bdf"
```

---

Given a byte array...

```
bytes = [107, 97, 155, 242, 36, 52, 182, 87, 67, 223, 163, 166, 7, 175, 123, 223];
```

You can convert the bytes to hexadecimal and then pad the resulting strings with leading `0`s...

```
hex = bytes.map { |b| b.to_s(16).rjust(2, '0') }
# => ["6b", "61", "9b", "f2", "24", "34", "b6", "57", "43", "df", "a3", "a6", "07", "af", "7b", "df"]
```

Then insert hyphens at the right places...

```
[4, 7, 10, 13].inject(hex) { |hex, n| hex.insert(n, '-') }
# => ["6b", "61", "9b", "f2", "-", "24", "34", "-", "b6", "57", "-", "43", "df", "-", "a3", "a6", "07", "af", "7b", "df"]
```

Then join the array:

```
hex.join
# => "6b619bf2-2434-b657-43df-a3a607af7bdf"
```

Answer (score -1):

First approximation answer:

```
a = [107, 97, 155, 242, 36, 52, 182, 87, 67, 223, 163, 166, 7, 175, 123, 223]
ah = a.map{ |i| i.to_s(16) }

puts [4,2,2,2,6].inject([]) { |result, idx| result << ah.slice!(0, idx).reverse.join }.join("-")

f29b616b-3424-57b6-df43-df7baf7a6a3
=> nil
```

There is almost certainly a cleaner way to do it, but this gives you something to work with. It uses inject to accumulate the generated uuid string sections into an array, then joins those into the guid.

Each block of the guid is a subarray of the byte array, seemingly ordered lsb to msb.

Comment: Last two parts are to be reversed to conform the result provided by OP.

Comment: thanks, I didn't notice that defficiency.  I'll leave it as is for now though.

Comment: BTW, what’s wrong with `map` since you already invented smart initial array? `[4,2,2,2,6].map { |idx| ah.slice!(0, idx).reverse.join }.join('-')` gives the same result as yours.

Comment: @mudasobwa nothing wrong with map - I actually was using it, then thought 'Ooh, lets see if I can do this with inject instead' :-)